# Prove minimum number of edges in a graph given constraints.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So essentially I was instructed to draw a graph with 8 vertices and 12 edges that satisfied the following constraints:

- Between every group of 3 vertices at least two are connected
- At most one connection can exist between an two vertices
- No vertex can be connected to itself

I was able to complete said graph and now I've been tasked with proving that it is impossible for such a graph to exist with fewer than 12 edges.

I was given a hint that it has something to do with each vertex having at least three connections (a degree of 3), but I don't know how one could come to that conclusion. How is it that you can just assume that each vertex has a degree of three?

Comment: From what I understand, the last two conditions says the graph is simple?

Comment: Yes I believe so.

Comment: Ok, there are $\binom{8}{3}=56$ triple of vertices. To satisfy the first condition, Each edge takes care of 6 pairs, So we need at least $\frac{56}{6}>9$ edges. And then those groups could have intersections, so we need more edges to cover those. So pick edge $v_1v_2$, the triples $(v_1,v_2,v_3),(v_1,v_2,v_4),...(v_1,v_2v_6)$ are covered by that edge.  Now, edge $v_2v_3$ covers 5 more: $(v_2,v_3,v_4),(v_2,v_3,v_5)...(v_2,v_3,v_8)$. Edge $V_3v_4$ covers 5 more... so on

Comment: Could you elaborate on the statement "Each edge takes care of 6 pairs"

Comment: I'm not really familiar with those terms. I've only be recently introduced to graph theory and I'm having difficulties understanding it

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to graph theory. A professional answer to your question is the following. Consider a complement $G’$ of the given graph $G$, that is $G’$ has the same set of $n=8$ vertices but any two distinct of them are adjacent in $G’$ iff they are not adjacent in $G$. That is, each edge between any two vertices belongs exactly to one of the graphs $G$ and $G’$. Thus in total $G$ and $G’$ have ${8 \choose 2}=28$ edges. The first condition means  that the graph $G’$ is triangle-free, that is has no cycles of length $3$. Then by [Turán's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n's_theorem) or even [Mantel's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n's_theorem#Mantel.27s_theorem) theorem, the graph $G’$ has at most $\lfloor{n^2\over4}\rfloor=16$ egdes, so the graph $G$ has at least $28-16=12$ edges.